# packet loss rate and netem

Tags: ping, packetloss

I am emulating a network with netem. I wrote a script that changes the network delay according to a linear function from 1 to 50ms every 15 seconds (with a normal variance = 5%).
The packet loss is 1%.

How can it be that using ping between two machines, the packet loss rate results to follow the delay curve? Shouldn't it be constant?

this is the ping command:

```
sudo ping 192.168.0.1 -i 0.01 -w 1 -n -q
```

here the graph for the packet loss rate over time.
[image: Packet Loss Rate for Ping]

Moreover, even though I set `-c 100`, the number of transmitted packets is slightly more than such a threshold, while the received packets happens to be exactly 100. Why? Yet on ping man it says:

> **-c count** : *Stop after sending count **ECHO_REQUEST** packets.*

here the graph for the packet transmitted over time
[image]

--- EDIT
I have noticed that if I set packet loss to 0%, this phenomenon is still present. So the losses are due to the delay introduced by netem. Probably the lost packets are the latecomers?